# Correct syntax to deploy azure group with parameters from VSTS build step?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines-build-task

How is it possible to carry out the 'azure group deployment create' command on a VSTS azure powershell build step, when it seems no way of expressing the parameters, or a parameter file, is parsed successfully?

I have no problem is doing the above in a local powershell, but get only an error when it comes to the --parameter definition part of the command, when performing this in a VSTS step on a default build agent, where azure cli is accessible.

As a simple example, how can this stock tutorial deployment be successfully run from a build step on a default build agent?

```
azure group deployment create name ExampleDeployment resource-group ExampleGroup template-uri "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/101-storage-account-create/azuredeploy.json" --parameters "{\"storageAccountType\":{\"value\":\"Standard_GRS\"}}"
```

Crucially, this part is failing:

```
--parameters "{\"storageAccountType\":{\"value\":\"Standard_GRS\"}}
```

which in my local powershell works fine, when expressed as:

```
--parameters "{'storageAccountType':{'value':'Standard_GRS'}}"
```

The process also fails if attempting to pickup the parameters from a .json file (although I need to get inline working, not external param file)

I've tried all variations of double and single quotes and escape characters when expressing the --parameters. Nothing is accepted.

Typical error for the inline --parameter is:

```
Parse error on line 1:
##[error]{'storageAccountType'
-^
Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'
```

And when attempting with an external parameter file:

```
Parse error on line 1:
##[error]@d:\a\1\s\params.jso
^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'
```

I have tried all the above with an without a separate npm install -g azure-cli on the build agent.

Many thanks

Comment: what does it have to do with powershell? why don't you use powershell on the build agent? looking at examples this is how it should work: `"{\"storageAccountType\":{\"value\":\"Standard_GRS\"}}"`

Comment: Hi - powershell is used on the build agent. The script is defined as part of a VSTS build step, copied to the agent and executed there. Where it fails to parse.

Comment: this is not powershell, this is azure cli, why don't you use powershell?

Comment: hmm. So I've now tried this in a Powershell VSTS step, rather than 'Azure Powershell' VSTS step.  Same result. Tried with:
azure group deployment create --name ExampleDeployment --resource-group example --template-uri "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/101-storage-account-create/azuredeploy.json" --parameters "{'storageAccountType':{'value':'Standard_GRS'}}"
Parse error on line 1:
{'storageAccountType'
-^
Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'

Comment: also tried with: azure group deployment create --name ExampleDeployment --resource-group example --template-uri "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/101-storage-account-create/azuredeploy.json" --parameters "{\"storageAccountType\":{\"value\":\"Standard_GRS\"}}"      Similar parse error

Comment: for powershell step use powershell cmdlets. not azure cli commands?

Comment: Thanks very much - that suggestion works! Azure Powershell step: New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ExampleDeployment -ResourceGroupName "myGroup" -TemplateUri "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/101-storage-account-create/azuredeploy.json" -storageAccountType "Standard_GRS"          Shame the original method against the azure cli didn't parse, yet could parse other commands such as azure create resource group. How can I mark your comment as the answer?

Comment: added the answer ;) thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use azure powershell to achieve the same thing:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ExampleDeployment -ResourceGroupName "myGroup" -TemplateUri "raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/‌​…; -storageAccountType "Standard_GRS"
```